# AS3 Keyboard events

Tags: actionscript-3, keyboard-events, event-listener

How would one go about adding event listeners for multiple keystrokes, for example if the up and right buttons are pressed player goes diagonally in that direction.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the following code, I store the pressed key in a object and then animated a sprite using the object :

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _keys:Object = { };
        private var _sprite:Sprite = new Sprite;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point

            _sprite.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000, 1);
            _sprite.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 40, 40);
            _sprite.graphics.endFill();
            _sprite.x = 100;
            _sprite.y = 100;
            addChild(_sprite);

            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }

        private function onKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
        {
            _keys[e.keyCode] = true;
        }

        private function onKeyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
        {
            _keys[e.keyCode] = false;   
        }

        private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void 
        {

            if (_keys[Keyboard.UP])
            {
                _sprite.y --;
            }

            if (_keys[Keyboard.DOWN])
            {
                _sprite.y ++;
            }

            if (_keys[Keyboard.RIGHT])
            {
                _sprite.x++;
            }

            if (_keys[Keyboard.LEFT])
            {
                _sprite.x--;
            }
        }

    }

}
```